# Как узнать расстояние между двумя точками (координаты долгота-широта) в Яндекс api?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, vba

Какой строчкой можно получить расстояние рассчитанное через Yandex Api если задать две координаты долготы-широты?

Имеется пример того что надо в гугл картах http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=60.185383%2C29.810629&destinations=60.176707%2C30.152734&mode=car&language=ru&sensor=false

В ответ я получаю строку из которой изымаю расстояние в VBA Excel.
Мне нужно то же самое, только от Яндекса.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Попробуйте поискать вот тут https://tech.yandex.ru/routing/distance_matrix/?from=mapsapi

Comment: Я правильно поняла, что у Яндекса нет такого же бесплатного как у гугла варианта? Для того что бы получить дистанцию между точками нужен apikey, а чтобы его получить надо оплатить apikey.

Comment: У Яндекса нет такого же бесплатного варианта. Может вам подойдет вариант высчитать расстояние напрямую? Не по дорогам?

Comment: Нужно по дорогам.
Буду гуглом тогда пользоваться.. Спасибо большое за разъяснения!